# Why are circle objects located in top left corner of an SVG container?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

The code below produces circles positioned in top left corner of the container. I'd like it to be at the position corresponding to the array values. 
Here's the code:

```
<script>
   var data = [ 30, 40, 50 ]

   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 800)
            .attr("height", 500)
            .style("border", "3px solid black");

   var circles = svg.selectAll("g")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g");

   circles.append("circle")
          .attr("cX", function(d) { return d; })
          .attr("cY", function(d) { return d; })
          .attr("r", 50 )
          .style("fill", "steelblue")

   circles.append("text")
          .text( function(d) { return d; })

</script>
```

Here's the DOM:

[image]

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/fLa5tLmo/ .

Comment: You are kidding right? If I merely copy past code, then it's acceptable. But, if I take a photo and paste it, it's not acceptable? That's ludicrous. This was a legitmate question after being stuck on it for 2 hours. Excuse me for not knowing everything about D3 after picking it up 2 days ago for the first time.

Comment: Because the origin (0,0) of an svg element is the top left.

Comment: The problem with pictures is that (a) you are not providing a *runnable* example (see also [mcve]) and (b) make it incredible hard for us to create a runnable example since we cannot copy the code. Copy and pasting the code basically takes no effort on your side, but duplicating the code from a *picture* to get something to play around with requires a lot of effort from us. However, the question might also have been downvoted because you didn't explain what result you expect. See [ask] for that.  (I didn't downvote btw)

Comment: Felix Kling, Okay, thank you for the description. I will make an edit. Eric Guan, I will look into that.

Comment: See the edit to my comment too. It's not clear why you are asking. The demo I created renders slightly differently, so are you wondering why you don't get the same result as I am or do you expect the origin of the coordinate system to be somewhere else?

Comment: To clarify, I'd like the x and y coordinate of each circle to be equal to the corresponding value of the data array. So, the first circle should have the coordinate of (30,30), and the second be located at (40,40), and so forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the use of `cX` and `cY`, which don't exist in SVG. The attributes are `cx` and `cy`, lowercase.

So, this:

```
circles.append("circle")
      .attr("cX", function(d) { return d; })
      .attr("cY", function(d) { return d; })
      .attr("r", 50 )
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
```

Should be this:

```
circles.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d; })
      .attr("r", 50 )
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
```

Every time you get your SVG elements in the top left corner (the SVG origin), suspect of a NaN or another problem setting the position attributes (`x`, `y`, `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, `cx`, `cy` etc...).

This is your code, changing only `cx` and `cy` (and changing the data to spread the circles a little more):

```js
   var data = [ 100, 200, 300 ]

   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 400)
            .style("border", "3px solid black");

   var circles = svg.selectAll("g")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g");

   circles.append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d) { return d; })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return d; })
          .attr("r", 50 )
          .style("fill", "steelblue")

   circles.append("text")
          .text( function(d) { return d; })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```